# Interactive ggPredict whitin R Shiny FlexDashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, ggiraph

I'm using Flexdashboard to create an R Shiny App; for the graph I'm using ggPredict() from **ggiraphExtra** package

This is the chunk that I need the following plot with a linear regressions using the mtcars dataset:

````
### Graph2
```{r}

renderPlot({
  Reg_LM <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = mtcars) 
  ggPredict(Reg_LM, interactive = F)
})

```
````

When I run my ggPredict with **interactive = F** my plot runs perfectly!

But when I add **interactive = T** (for a much better experience) my plot simply disappears (doesnt return any error message)

My guess is that R Shiny doesnt support **interactive = T** from ggPredict. Could be that? Or FlexDashboard needs another way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try using the `htmlwidget` render and output functions: `renderggiraph` and `ggiraphOutput`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @RyanMorton

Here's the code working perfectly:

````
### Graph2
```{r}

output$plot5 <- renderggiraph({

  ggiraph(code = print(ggPredict(lm(mpg ~ disp + hp + drat, data = mtcars),
                                 colorAsFactor = T,
                                 point = F)))
})

ggiraphOutput("plot5")


```
````